# In EF 4, can a subset of columns be represented by a class in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

Let's say I have the following tables setup in SQL Server (2008)

[image]

Is there a way to generate the EDMX such that in my project Height, Weight and Age are properties of a public non entity class called `Characteristics` and that in code, I can address them as

```
ABoy.Characteristics.Height
ABoy.Characteristics.Weight
ABoy.Characteristics.Age

AGirl.Characteristics.Height
AGirl.Characteristics.Weight
AGirl.Characteristics.Age
```

I want to do this, because in my actual case, there other methods on my Characteristic class.
I do not want a common table, because Characteristic need not necessarily be tracked by EF unless they are added to a BOY or GIRL class.

**EDIT:** Writing this down made me realize that I could just have a partial class with a Characteristic type exposed for BOY and GIRL and it would just return an object of type Characteristic. I would also have a tracker to always return the same object per instance of BOY or GIRL and to update it if a modification came in.
I'll leave this open for other suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also accomplish while allowing standard EF CRUD operations by using [Table-per-type inheritance](http://www.robbagby.com/entity-framework/entity-framework-modeling-table-per-type-inheritance/) where your base type may look like:

```
Person
{
  public <guid/int> ID { get; set; }
  public <type> Height { get; set; }
  public <type> Weight { get; set; }
  public <type> Age { get; set; }
}
```

with Inheritence Tables types:

```
Boy
{
  public <guid/int> ID { get; set; }
}

Girl
{
  public <guid/int> ID { get; set; }
}
```

(3 tables total)

Allowing you to do standard operation in EF pretty effectively.  I'd also highly recommend reading up on the performance of Type per Table inheritance, although with a simple table structure like this it shouldn't hinder you.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with a database view. Entity Framework will allow you to import views as entities. Keep in mind views will not support CRUD operations.

Also, you will need to include a primary key or some way of EF identifying rows uniquely. Otherwise, you will get a number of rows with identical data.

In code, you could have an AddCharacteristic(Boy boy, Characteristic characteristic) method to set those properties on your Boy (or Girl) class.